# Simulate no network using Retrofit and MockWebServer

Tags: android, retrofit, mockwebserver

I want to simulate the no network case when using `RetroFit` and `MockWebServer`.

Im currently testing using `Espresso` and supplying the `MockWebServer`s url to the `RestAdapter` before I start my tests. This works great for mocking server responses and so on but I cant see a simple way to script the `java.net.ConnectException` exception thrown when a device has no network. I can see the MockResponse allows throttling simulation and so on but not a custom exception.

I know I could go the root of mocking the actual web api interface used by `retrofit` but I would like to use the same approach as my other tests if possible by using `MockWebServer`.

I imagine I've just missed something simple :)

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Retrofit has a `retrofit-mock` module which offers a `MockRestAdapter` class whose purpose is to simulate network delay and errors.

This is a used in conjunction with the normal `RestAdapter` to create an instance of your service. You can see a full example in the `samples/mock-github-client/` folder of the repo: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/parent-1.9.0/retrofit-samples/mock-github-client

`MockRestAdapter` offers these APIs:

- `setDelay` - Set the network round trip delay, in milliseconds.
- `setVariancePercentage` - Set the plus-or-minus variance percentage of the network round trip delay.
- `setErrorPercentage` - Set the percentage of calls to `calculateIsFailure()` that return `true`.

In your test, you can call `setErrorPercentage(100)` to guarantee that a network error will occur. By default the amount of time for the error to be thrown is anywhere from 0 to 3x the delay. Set the delay to 0 for instant results.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-mock/src/test/java/retrofit2/mock/MockRetrofitTest.java

Comment: Sir,i try to override the baseurl of retrofit to the one from mockwebserver, but then i still end up making a webservice call when performing the test, is there a way to stop that? Please assist. @tony19, Jake Wharton

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to simulate network issues with MockWebServer is by setting the SocketPolicy to SocketPolicy.DISCONNECT_AT_START, SocketPolicy.NO_RESPONSE or etc:

```
MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();

MockResponse response = new MockResponse()
  .setSocketPolicy(SocketPolicy.DISCONNECT_AT_START);

server.enqueue(response);
```

This way you can simulate network errors like connection prematurely closed before response or Timeout exceptions

Answer (score 7):

to be clear with whe types of exceptions here you can see the differences:

[Internet Connection Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573176/internet-connection-error)

So you can get two types:

**UnknownHostException** - When you don't have internet or unknown host... to simulate this, set to the adapter an incorrect end point.

**ConnectException** - mockwebserver can throw a timeout exception. You can see how to do it here:

https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Really I don't know how your code is, but I hope this is useful

Comment: +1 thanks for answering but it does not really answer the question as I want to simulate no network as opposed to a timeout. Dispatchers interesting though. I wonder if i can throw the above exceptions though that...

Comment: seems I cant as the network exceptions are checked and the dispatcher only throws Inturrupted as per its interface

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's useful, but you can simulate a timeout with MockWebServer:

```
String contentType = "Content-type: application/json";
MockResponse response = MockResponse().setResponseCode(statusCode).setBody(responseBody).addHeader(contentType);
MockWebServer proxy = new MockWebServer();
proxy.enqueue(response);
proxy.setBodyDelayTimeMs(timeoutDelay));
proxy.play(10000); //Number port - Important!!!
```

Note: Please, set HttpClient of your code (e.g. AsyncHttpClient) with that number port for testing purpose.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is pointing the Retrofit URL (end-point) to a random non-existent host .
I used "thisIsARandomHost.com" and bingo i was able to mock the unknown host exception.

For example :  setAPP_URL = "http://thisIsARandomHost.com/";

Here , setAPP_URL is the string variable that contains my url which I pass on to retrofit , when I want to mock unknown host exception in my tests I set the url as above .For all other purposes it is set to the valid URL required by my app.

As stated in above answers , MockWebServer is a great library for mocking retrofit responses , but you don't need that library for mocking this exception . For mocking all other exceptions I would recommend MockWebServer , I use it a lot in my project for testing responses.

Note : You can set the app url to anything as long as that url doesn't exist on the web.

Answer (score 1):

`mockWebServer.shutdown()` before executing your unit test is fine.

Internally it closes the socket connection:

```
serverSocket!!.close()
```